# Mathcad iteration with condition

Tags: function, while-loop, find, iteration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2dwQ.jpg)trying to do a iteration in Mathcad, but all new to the program. This i my scrip so far. Script attached. Trying to find two variables (x,y0) with the **find** function in Mathcad. Works perfectly. But there is a condition that must be forfilled. The last equation in the scrip must equal 0. How do i extend the script so it automatically try some random numbers defined in a matrix or vector and runs through the calcutaion until the last equation is forfilled.

I tried to use the **while** function but could not get it to work along with the find function.

Thanks in regards